# Stream audio/video over RTSP with VLC?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, streaming, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a camera module (noIR) and USB mic attached to my raspberry pi.  I'm trying to setup a RTSP streaming video/audio so I can observe the feed from another system on my network.

So far, I've been able to get video streaming working with:

```
raspivid -h 972 -w 1296 -fps 12 -br 46 -o - -t 0 | cvlc -v stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264
```

However, I can't figure out how to add the audio track to the RTSP stream from my USB mic.  Thanks for your help!